# python virtual environments and roaming profiles

Tags: python, python-venv

If I have a python project in my documents folder on a school computer (Windows), and create a virtual environment, it works fine on that computer. When I go to another computer, my Documents folder and all the contents are there for me, as expected (roaming profiles doing it's job). But when I go to open my python project again (using vs code), the virtual environment may not work since python may be set up differently on that computer. What's a good way to deal with this? Create a new virtual environment each time I am on a different computer? Or is there an easier way? Or should this be working, but I am doing something wrong?

Comment: yes, you should be creating a new virtual environment. Whatever project your are working one should be packaged, or at least, it's dependencies should be enumerated explicitly, even if just a `requirements.txt` file. Then creating a new virtual environment is trivial.